# What is the Jenkins variable containing the Perforce changelist that triggered the build?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, perforce

I have a Jenkins job set to poll Perforce for changes and build when a changelist is submitted.

I'd like to deploy the build artifacts to a folder which contains the changelist as part of the path - e.g. D:\JenkinsBuilds\$JOB_NAME\$PERFORCE_CHANGELIST\

What is the Jenkins variable containing the Perforce changelist number that triggered the build?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called P4_CHANGELIST.

See the Helix Perforce [plugin documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/jenkins/Content/P4Jenkins/variable-expansion.html) for more details.

Comment: That is the variable I was looking for, though the value seems to always be set to the max CL in P4 as opposed to the max CL of the P4 mapping in the job configuration.  So if I set off the build manually, I get an unrelated CL number...

Comment: The URL has changed since 2012, but I found the variables listed here: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/jenkins/Content/P4Jenkins/variable-expansion.html

Comment: Thanks for the update @enno, I've changed my answer to link to the new URL.